# How to expose Sitecore Analytics Reports Data to outside system

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

I need to expose Page Views data for different pages for each channels to an outside non-sitecore system through an API.
I checked the [ReportingAPI](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/reporting-api.html) documentation shows how to query the reporting database but there is no details about getting the similar reports in sitecore using the API.
How we can expose these kind of reporting data?

Sitecore Version: 9.2

Comment: Have you managed to expose data externally and how?
PS: i dont have enough reputation to paste a comment